# Key strokes through QuickType predictions will not call UITextfield delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361566/quicktype-predictions-take-key-strokes-into-account-that-should-be-blocked-by-my) and I believe it is a **bug**.

For any key strokes inserted into my UITextfield with Quicktype, it will not call

```
textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
```

method.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: It looks like the post you reference was removed

Comment: Oh, wrong url, I will fix it now